# Finding spring batch instances which are X days old

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

Currently I have restart `spring-batch` job in place which is running each hour and checking DB via `JobExplorer` for job instances which failed, it picks up latest job instance for job which is failed and restarts latest execution. This works fine but we have now new request to restart not only latest instance but all instances which fall in `X` day window and we should restart one at time from oldest one until it falls out of this window.

Example:

- Job `A` has instance `jobInstance1` which fail at 8pm
- Job `A` has instance `jobInstance2` which fail at 9pm
- restart kicks in first time at 10pm and first restarts `jobInstance1`
- `jobInstance1` now succeed
- restart kicks in second time at 11pm and restarts `jobInstance2`

I am thinking about two options:

1. Use `JobExplorer` and combination of `List<JobInstance> getJobInstances(String jobName, int start, int count);` and `int getJobInstanceCount(String jobName) throws NoSuchJobException;` and to walk through list to find what I am looking for by checking start time
2. Extend `JdbcJobInstanceDao` and write my own query against `JOB_INSTANCE` table joined with `JOB_EXECUTION` and use that

Is there better way to fetch all failed job instances of some job which are at most 3 days old and sort them oldest first?

What do you think about option 1 and 2 if there is no better way?

Comment: I'd go option B (or even write your own DAO independent of ours).  The Spring Batch schema is pretty stable so you shouldn't have issues with long term compatibility with that approach.

Comment: Thanks I was leaning to that option as well, I wanted to see does anybody have better idea. Why is getting executions by status or by execution time not already implemented on some of job support classes? It sounds to me like pretty common requirement

Comment: By time itself isn't actually asked for that much.  Knowing the most recent is (aka the last failure) is what we see more.  However, contributions are always welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing my own `JobInstanceDao` as [Michael Minella](https://stackoverflow.com/users/618059/michael-minella) suggested. I needed it only in restart job so I did not extend spring batch one, but I used spring batch one as example. Here is implementation if anyone needs it:

```
package com.custom.package;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.List;

import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobInstance;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.ParameterizedRowMapper;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;

@Component
public class CustomJobInstanceDao {

    public static final String BATCH_TABLE_PREFIX = "BATCH";

    private static final String GET_JOBS_WITH_STATUS_AFTER_DATE = "SELECT ji.JOB_INSTANCE_ID, ji.JOB_NAME FROM %PREFIX%_JOB_EXECUTION je LEFT JOIN %PREFIX%_JOB_INSTANCE ji "
            + " ON je.JOB_INSTANCE_ID = ji.JOB_INSTANCE_ID WHERE ji.JOB_NAME = ? AND je.STATUS = ? AND je.START_TIME > ? GROUP BY  je.JOB_INSTANCE_ID";

    private static final String GET_RUNNING_JOBS_AFTER_DATE = "SELECT ji.JOB_INSTANCE_ID, ji.JOB_NAME FROM %PREFIX%_JOB_EXECUTION je LEFT JOIN %PREFIX%_JOB_INSTANCE ji "
            + " ON je.JOB_INSTANCE_ID = ji.JOB_INSTANCE_ID WHERE ji.JOB_NAME = ? AND je.END_TIME is NULL AND je.START_TIME > ? GROUP BY  je.JOB_INSTANCE_ID";

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public List<JobInstance> getJobInstancesWithStatusAfterStartDate(final String jobName, final String status,
            final DateTime afterStartTime) {

        return jdbcTemplate.query(getQuery(GET_JOBS_WITH_STATUS_AFTER_DATE), new Object[] {jobName, status,
                afterStartTime.toDate()}, new JobInstanceRowMapper());
    }

    public List<JobInstance> getRunningJobInstancesAfterStartDate(final String jobName, final DateTime afterStartTime) {

        return jdbcTemplate.query(getQuery(GET_RUNNING_JOBS_AFTER_DATE),
                new Object[] {jobName, afterStartTime.toDate()}, new JobInstanceRowMapper());
    }

    private String getQuery(final String base) {
        return StringUtils.replace(base, "%PREFIX%", BATCH_TABLE_PREFIX);
    }

    private final class JobInstanceRowMapper implements ParameterizedRowMapper<JobInstance> {

        public JobInstanceRowMapper() {
        }

        @Override
        public JobInstance mapRow(final ResultSet rs, final int rowNum) throws SQLException {
            final JobInstance jobInstance = new JobInstance(rs.getLong(1), rs.getString(2));
            // should always be at version=0 because they never get updated
            jobInstance.incrementVersion();
            return jobInstance;
        }
    }

}
```